# Selecting log level in ROS2 launch file

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nodes defined in launch file have the INFO log level as a default value
I would like to know how to change it so that it also logs DEBUG level strings or other types of logging.

```
launch_ros.actions.Node(package='demo_nodes_cpp', node_executable='talker', output='screen', parameters=[config_file])
```

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311471/selecting-log-level-in-ros2-launch-file/) by [Teckel](https://answers.ros.org/users/37289/teckel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2018-12-25

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yossi_ov](https://answers.ros.org/users/31601/yossi_ov/) on 2019-11-11**:
Any updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have had the same issue and for me (on Eloquent) the following works:

```
logger = launch.substitutions.LaunchConfiguration("log_level")
launch.LaunchDescription([
      launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "log_level",
            default_value=["debug"],
            description="Logging level",
      ),
     launch_ros.actions.Node(
         package='demo_nodes_cpp',
         executable='talker',
         output='screen', 
         arguments=['--ros-args', '--log-level', logger]
    )
])
```

I got this idea from this open issue: https://github.com/ros2/launch/issues/383 and hopefully a more elegant solution will be available soon.

If anyone has an idea for a better solution in the meantime, please share!

---

Originally posted by [notarobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/62541/notarobot/) with karma: 46 on 2020-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tnajjar](https://answers.ros.org/users/36992/tnajjar/) on 2022-07-14**:
This sets the level for all loggers including rcl which spams a lot. To set the logging level only for your node see [here](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Demos/Logging-and-logger-configuration.html#:%7E:text=ros2%20run%20logging_demo%20logging_demo_main%20%2D%2Dros%2Dargs%20%2D%2Dlog%2Dlevel%20logger_usage_demo%3A%3Ddebug)

(Available from galactic)

**Comment by [LastStarDust](https://answers.ros.org/users/134345/laststardust/) on 2023-02-13**:
@tnajjar That is true. I found a solution by using the `PythonExpression` substitution.

```
    node_test = LifecycleNode(
        package="node_test",
        executable="note_test",
        name="note_test",
        namespace="",
        output="screen",
        ros_arguments=[
            "--log-level",
            PythonExpression(['"node_test:=" + "', log_level, '"']),
        ],
    )
```

But this is a very sinful piece of code because it allows a maleficent user to execute arbitrary Python code. Do you know any better solution?

**Comment by [tnajjar](https://answers.ros.org/users/36992/tnajjar/) on 2023-02-16**:
you don't need PythonExpression

```
 arguments= [
    "--ros-args",
    "--log-level",
    "node_test:=debug",
]
```

this should work

**Comment by [LastStarDust](https://answers.ros.org/users/134345/laststardust/) on 2023-02-21**:
@tnajjar That works if I want to keep the log level at "debug", but what if I want to change the log level as a command line argument?

If I write:

```
log_level_arg = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    "log-level",
    default_value=["debug"],
    description="Logging level",
)
log_level = LaunchConfiguration("log-level")

...

some_node = LifecycleNode(
    arguments= [
        "--ros-args",
        "--log-level",
        "some_node:=",
        log_level
    ]
```

then a white space is added between `"some_node:="` and `log_level` and everything breaks down.

**Comment by [tnajjar](https://answers.ros.org/users/36992/tnajjar/) on 2023-03-06**:
try:

```
some_node = LifecycleNode(
    arguments= [
        "--ros-args",
        "--log-level",
        ["some_node:=", log_level],
    ]
```

**Comment by [LastStarDust](https://answers.ros.org/users/134345/laststardust/) on 2023-03-23**:
@tnajjar Thank you so much. That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know this question was asked before dashing was released, and that eloquent is being released soon with changed syntax...

But for dashing, you can use the following syntax:

```
  launch_ros.actions.Node(package='demo_nodes_cpp',
    node_executable='talker',
    output='screen', 
     parameters=[config_file],
    arguments=[('__log_level:=debug')])
```

This will set the log level to debug for every node being run in this process (rcl, rclcpp, the rmw layer). I don't know how to restrict the log changes to just "talker" node unfortunately. I think logging is still a work in progress.

---

Originally posted by [johnconn](https://answers.ros.org/users/43713/johnconn/) with karma: 553 on 2019-11-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rasmusan-](https://answers.ros.org/users/53040/rasmusan-/) on 2020-09-10**:
Can anyone update on how to do this in Eloquent/Foxy? The direct translation to the new command line format does not work:

```
launch_ros.actions.Node(
    package='demo_nodes_cpp',
    executable='talker',
    output='screen', 
    arguments=[('--ros-args --log-level debug')]
)
```

**Comment by [trunc8](https://answers.ros.org/users/44889/trunc8/) on 2021-08-15**:
The arguments must be given in a list of strings in Foxy as shown below.

```
launch_ros.actions.Node(
    package='demo_nodes_cpp',
    executable='talker',
    output='screen', 
    arguments=['--ros-args', '--log-level', 'debug']
)
```

The accepted answer achieves the same result as the above code.